# How to activate webcamera to take snapshot with js

Tags: javascript, php

I am making backend application on php and was curious is it possible to take a snapshot with webcamera via js instead of taking picture , downloading it to the hard drive and than to upload it via input file?
I hope you understand the core of the issue! The idea is to upload image directly after user press button "Take snapshot"

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Snapshot with webcamera". If the snapshot is refering to the web page itself, then you may take a look at this: https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Comment: I mean to take a picture with the camera when user press the button

Comment: Ok, so you may take a look at the official MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/B2G_OS/API/Camera_API/Introduction Though IE mobile, Opera Mobile and Safari are NOT supported. Alternatively, try webcamjs (be aware, though, that chrome requires HTTPS to work with it, while IE requires flash player)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a js library that uses flash only in a HTML5 fallback situation:

https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs

```
    <script src="librarypath.js"></script>

    <div id="cameraId"></div>
    <div id="cameraResultId"></div>

    <script language="JavaScript">
        Webcam.attach( '#cameraId' );

        function snapshot() {
            Webcam.snap( function(data_uri) {
SendJson = {};                
SendJson["image"] = data_uri;
                SendJson=JSON.stringify(SendJson);


                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: respective_page.php,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType:'application/json',
                    data:SendJson,
                    success: function(data){

                        alert('Uploaded Succefully')
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                       handleErrors('Error: ' , textStatus , errorThrown);
                    }
                });

            } );
        }
    </script>

    <a href="javascript:void(snapshot())">Snapshot</a>
```

Comment: This looks very promising as it does takes shot when you press button but how to upload it directly Adi?Thanks

Comment: write ajax call in snapshot() method where you can send the data_uri directly to the respective server side code and continously to database

Comment: Now look at the updated code and make a php page which should read ur JSON and send to the dp

Comment: Huge Thank you Adi!